# Detect the type of strings

Tags: python-3.x, string, python-2.7

I want to create a python script that uses strings in byte format that can be written to a file.

So the problem is something like this:

```
packed_int = struct.pack('>I', 1234)
result = packed_int + data
```

Here is the problem: In python 3 this will give an error because of concatenation between str and bytes.

So I solved the problem with the following code:

```
data = data.encode('utf-8')
packed_int = struct.pack('>I', 1234)
result = packed_int + data
```

Now if the data is already in bytes format this will give an error of not having an encode method. So I did this:

```
if type(data) is not bytes:
    data = data.encode('utf-8')
```

The final problem is the fact that in python 2 the last snippet does not work.

How can I solve the problem without checking for python version?

Comment: Python 2 will reach end-of-life in 8 months (https://pythonclock.org/) – I wouldn't write new code to target it, unless you explicitly have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `hasattr` for [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing):

```py
if hasattr(data, 'encode'):
    data = data.encode('utf-8')
```

Or you do something like this, which is what the [`six`](https://github.com/benjaminp/six/blob/8da94b8a153ceb0d6417d76729ba75e80eaa75c1/six.py) compatibility library does:

```
import sys

PY3 = sys.version_info[0] == 3
binary_type = (bytes if PY3 else str)
text_type = (str if PY3 else unicode)

# ...

if isinstance(data, text_type):
    data = data.encode('utf-8')
```